# mod_wsgi authorization with Django users from postgres database

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, django, mod-wsgi

I am trying to protect a url path with basic auth and want to use the users from my Django application which are stored in a Postgres database. The user `app` is allowed to access this database, the web application works fine, but the authentication script runs with the wrong user.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app user=app group=www-data home=/app
<VirtualHost>
  # other stuff here

  <Location /admin/protected>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Login Required"
    Require valid-user
    AuthBasicProvider wsgi
    WSGIAuthUserScript  /app/scripts/auth.wsgi
  </Location>

  WSGIScriptAlias   /   /app/django.wsgi
  WSGIProcessGroup  app
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the error I get in my logs:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "www-data"
```

Is there a way to change the user with which the `auth.wsgi` script runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache authentication system checks are performed in the Apache worker processes and not in the WSGI daemon process. The Apache authentication system only says whether a user is permitted to access the web application. It doesn't change the user that the worker process runs as and it will keep running as the Apache user. If you are trying to use database trust based access based on what user the client runs as, it will not work.

Your only option would be to run the whole of Apache as the 'app' user by setting the global Apache User directive. This is not likely what you really want to do. Or configure the database to allow access by the 'www-data' user.